# Restructure Date in R

Tags: r, date

I have dataset like:

```
 CODE    NAME    DATE      HOUR
  1       Ab    01-01-19     1
  1       Ab    02-01-19     2
  1       Ab    03-01-19     3
  1       Ab    04-01-19     4
  2       Xy    01-JAN-19    1
  2       Xy    02-JAN-19    2
  2       Xy    03-JAN-19    3
  2       Xy    04-JAN-19    4
```

Actual data set is much bigger. I want to convert all the DATE's in 01-JAN-19 format. 
I tried with:

```
a <- as.Date(df$DATE, format = "%d-%b-%y")
b <- as.Date(df$DATE, format = "%d-%m-%y")
a[is.na(a)] <- b[!is.na(b)]
df$ <- a
```

But it's taking time & giving result in 2019-01-01 format. Even I tried with:

```
df$DATE <- format(as.Date(df$DATE, format = c("%d-%b-%y", "%d-%m-%y")), "%d-%b-%y")
```

It's giving the desired result but it's filling alternate NA values in DATE column like:

```
 CODE    NAME    DATE      HOUR
  1       Ab    01-JAN-19    1
  1       Ab    NA           2
  1       Ab    03-JAN-19    3
  1       Ab    NA           4
  2       Xy    NA           1
  2       Xy    02-JAN-19    2
  2       Xy    NA           3
  2       Xy    04-JAN-19    4
```

I think it's because of `format = c("%d-%b-%y", "%d-%m-%y")`. How can I convert all DATE's into 01-JAN-19 format.

Comment: the format YYYY-MM-DD is the standard ISO format, and it is internal is saved as numeric, if you change it to any other format it will be a character date not a numeric date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
df$DATE = format(lubridate::parse_date_time(df$DATE, c('dmy','dby')), '%d-%b-%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Using the input data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, in `toDate` use the `tryFormats` argument of `as.Date`.  `as.Date` assumes all entries have the same format so `lapply` over the input to apply it individually to each element and then concatenate the resulting list back to a `Date` vector.  Now use `toDate` to convert `DATE` to `Date` class and then format it and convert to upper case. No packages are used.

```
toDate <- function(x, formats = c("%d-%m-%y", "%d-%b-%y")) {
  do.call("c", lapply(x, as.Date, tryFormats = formats))
}

transform(df, DATE = toupper(format(toDate(DATE), "%d-%b-%Y")))
```

**2)** Another approach is to just convert those entries not already in the desired format.  Again, no packages are used.

```
ok <- grepl("[A-Z]", df$DATE)
transform(df, DATE = 
  replace(DATE, !ok, toupper(format(as.Date(DATE[!ok], "%d-%m-%y"), "%d-%b-%y")))
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "CODE    NAME    DATE      HOUR
  1       Ab    01-01-19     1
  1       Ab    02-01-19     2
  1       Ab    03-01-19     3
  1       Ab    04-01-19     4
  2       Xy    01-JAN-19    1
  2       Xy    02-JAN-19    2
  2       Xy    03-JAN-19    3
  2       Xy    04-JAN-19    4"
df <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: This is giving error as ```Error: unexpected '=' in "transform(df, df$DATE ="```

Comment: I had made a correction to it and I guess you saw it before I fixed it. Try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I would try something like this

```
df$DATE = format(as.Date(df$DATE, format = ifelse(grepl(paste0(letters[1:26],collapse = '|'), df$DATE, ignore.case = TRUE), "%d-%b-%y", "%d-%m-%y")), format = "%d-%b-%y")
```

Hope this helps

## Test

```
# ifelse
format(as.Date(df$DATE, format = ifelse(grepl(paste0(letters[1:26],collapse = '|'), df$DATE, ignore.case = TRUE), "%d-%b-%y", "%d-%m-%y")), format = "%d-%b-%Y") 
[1] "01-Jan-2019" "02-Jan-2019" "03-Jan-2019" "04-Jan-2019" "01-Jan-2019"
[6] "02-Jan-2019" "03-Jan-2019" "04-Jan-2019"

# lubridate
format(lubridate::parse_date_time(df$DATE, c('dmy','dby')), '%d-%b-%Y')
[1] "01-Jan-2019" "02-Jan-2019" "03-Jan-2019" "04-Jan-2019" "01-Jan-2019"
[6] "02-Jan-2019" "03-Jan-2019" "04-Jan-2019"
```

Comment: This won't work. It's jus added 01-JAN-19 and 01-01-19 alternatively in DATE column.

Comment: It should I think. See test (just forgot to say to swap 'date' in the original answer with 'df$DATE'). Anyway you got valid answers already from other contributors

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following base R code

```
df$DATE<- as.Date(z <- gsub("[A-Z]\\K([A-Z]+)","\\L\\1",df$DATE),
                  format = ifelse(grepl("[[:alpha:]]",z),"%d-%b-%y","%d-%m-%y"))
```

such that

```
> df
  CODE NAME       DATE HOUR
1    1   Ab 2019-01-01    1
2    1   Ab 2019-01-02    2
3    1   Ab 2019-01-03    3
4    1   Ab 2019-01-04    4
5    2   Xy 2019-01-01    1
6    2   Xy 2019-01-02    2
7    2   Xy 2019-01-03    3
8    2   Xy 2019-01-04    4
```